# Formula that splits data into separate sections based on a divider (blank cell)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, transpose, flatten

I am trying to find a formula which splits data into separate columns based on a blank column.

As this is imported through another sheet and uses a divider:

[image: Picture of the image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(IF(INDIRECT("A2:A"&MAX((ROW(A2:A))*(A2:A<>"")))="", 
 "×", A2:A), " ", "¤"),,9^9), "×"))), " "))), "¤", " "))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(1/(1/SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(
 SPLIT(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(IF(INDIRECT("A1:"&MAX((ROW(A1:A))*(A1:A<>"")))="", 
 "×", A1:A), " ", "¤"),,9^9+0), "×"))), " "))), "¤", " "))))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!
Would there be a way to let's say only get the 2nd row?

Comment: Also this messes up date values. How would I be able to fix that?

Comment: @Ben to not mess up dates change INDEX to ARRAYFORMULA

Comment: @Ben to get 2nd row wrap it all into `QUERY( <formula here>, "limit 1 offset 1", )`

Comment: array formula still doesn't fix it

Comment: @Ben can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Hello!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VvgnlH5XOx_-d5c4ftNRnXkHNA1u5-TWSEzirsXp4fc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ben see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KB_fFWS3c2KS3t1RHu1bbE9Dlaa7r51eh2AJxjHugEQ/copy answer updated